# Getting JSON value in JSP

Tags: jquery, json, jsp

In my JSP (index.jsp), I am submitting a form that passes the Parameters to another JSP (action.jsp) using JSON.

```
<form id="form">
 <input type="text" name="name"/>
 <input type="button" id="btn" value="OK"/> 
</form>
```

And here is the Jquery Code of index.jsp :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btn").click(function(){
   var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
   $.ajax({
                    cache:false,
                    url:"action.jsp",
                    data:{name:name},
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function (msg) {
                       alert("SUCCESS");
                       // here I want a String that is 
                       // generated(generatedString) in action.jsp.
                        });
                       }
                    },
                    error:function () {
                        alert("Unable to add.");
                    }
        }); 

 });
});
```

My action.jsp code :

```
<%
   String name = request.getParameter("name");
   String generatedString = "E5142"; 
   response.setContentType("application/json");
   out.print(generatedString);
%>
```

The form is submitted to action.jsp successfully but cannot get the value 'generatedString' in index.jsp in return.

UPDATED: index.jsp always showing error in alert : "Unable to add." 
Tried what is said in comments, but didn't come up with success message.

Comment: I dont know JSP but it looks like youre just defining your variables not printing them? You need to print out the string in json.

Comment: In action.jsp, try adding another line `out.print(generatedString)`. Then inside of your `success` callback replace `alert("SUCCESS")` with `alert(msg)`

Comment: See this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279339/ajax-post-cannot-send-data-to-servelet/26280336#26280336)

Comment: tried but didn't work;

Comment: maybe the url is wrong, that is why you get the error message. Make user that action.jsp is in the same level(folder) with index.jsp

Comment: and if the url is correct, then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902008/retrieve-the-data-sent-as-json-from-javascript-inside-a-servlet on how to retrieve json values from javascript in jsp

Comment: that is not an issue dear. I have set the JSP in debug mode, Like what I said , it successfully passes the control to action.jsp, but always showing error in alert .@MaVRoSCy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send response from a jsp page you can use `out.println()`.

```
<%
   String jsonString= request.getParameter("name");
   String generatedString = "E5142";
   out.println(generatedString);
%>
```

In your jquery you can use `alert(msg)`;

But your problem is about action.jsp url path or jsp file. Because you are getting error in jquery send action! In google chrome open your console (**press F12**). Send your action and you can see error on console. If you get "**404 error**" this is a path error. If you get "**500 error**" this a jsp file error. Control your system log for what is going on.

Can you try this:

```
var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
var url = "action.jsp";
$.post(url,{name:name})
    .done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log('fail');
    });
```

Comment: There is no error in the console... Still getting error.

Comment: I added post sample. Can u try that?

Comment: Can you send your project structure?

Comment: Thank u @hurricane for you help, I had to stop the project